# How to use Join in Data Flow of Azure Data Factory efficiently?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

If I have 4 sources to join in table then should I need 4 join activity in graph of data flow? Is there any way to minimize Join activity.
For example: Suppose there are 20 sources to join then it will be more complex.

[image]

Comment: join only support two input streams. If your source  are in same database, you could try use query to let the join be simple. Just for now, there's a good solution for this even it will be more complex.

Comment: Hi @Dinesh Madhup, if you have any other concerns, please feel free to let me know. May I post it as answer?

Comment: @LeonYue Sure. it will be the answer. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome. I'm glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Join active](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join) only support two input streams. If your sources are in same database, you could try use query to let the join be simple.

Just for now, there's a good solution for this even it will be more complex.